# How do you combine the errors resulting from measuring one instrument with another?

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

In a recent lab, we were asked to find the *time constant*, $\tau$ by timing the discharge of a capacitor through a resistor. The voltage on the capacitor was measured with a DMM whose instrumentation error was found to be $\pm(0.3\%)\mathrm{V}$. The time to discharge was measured with a stopwatch which had an instrumentation error of $\pm0.01\mathrm{s}$. Both the stopwatch and the voltmeter also had observation errors. I equated the stopwatch's observation error to be my reaction time (approx. $\pm0.1\mathrm{s}$), and the observation error on the voltmeter to be my confidence in the range of voltage that I could confidently read (approx. $\pm0.3\mathrm{V}$); the voltage on the display was changing rapidly, so I approximated my ability to keep up with the rapidly changing display, as well as its resolution to be able to catch the value in question.

How would I go about combining these two errors to have a total error in units of $(\mathrm{s})$ for the measured time constant? There isn't an equation to do error propagation on as there is no calculation being performed. I am simply measuring one instrument with another.

Comment: Your estimate of your reaction time seems to be off by at least an order of magnitude

Comment: @DanDan0101 thank you. My mistake. It was supposed to be $0.12\mathrm{s}\approx0.1\mathrm{s}$. Edited now.

Comment: If I understand your issue, you know the initial voltage on the capacitor, and once you initiate discharge of the capacitor through a resistor you measure the capacitor voltage V at some time t.  Are the errors you quote considered to be standard deviations of V and t, and if not what are these errors?  Do you have more than one set of measured (V, t) values or just one?

Answer (score 2):

> There isn't an equation to do error propagation on as there is no calculation being performed.

Actually, this is the core misconception here. There is a calculation for doing error propagation here. I assume from your description that the governing equation that you are using is: $$v(t) = v_0 \ e^{-t/\tau}$$ and since your goal is to calculate $\tau$ you can solve that equation to obtain $$\tau (v,t) = \frac{t}{\ln(v_0/v)}$$

This is the governing equation. You can plug this into the propagation of errors formula to obtain $$\sigma_\tau^2 = \left(\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}\right)^2 \sigma_t^2+\left(\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial v}\right)^2 \sigma_v^2$$ $$ \sigma_\tau^2 = \frac{1}{\ln(v_0/v)^2} \sigma_t^2 + \frac{t^2}{v^2 \ln(v_0/v)^4} \sigma_v^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

A few comments.  The development by Dale for the variance for $\tau$ assumes the two measurements- for $v$ and $t$- are independent variables.  Also, you may have more than one set of measurements for $v$ and $t$, and therefore more than one estimate for $\tau$.  Assume you have a set of $n$ measurements and thus $n$ values for $\tau$ each with variance as Dale provided.  The standard deviation for $\tau$ from all the measurements is   $\sigma_{\tau best} =( {\sum_{i=1}^{n} {1 \over {\sigma_i^2}}})^{-{1 \over 2}}$.  The larger the number of measurements ($n$) the less the uncertainty for $\tau$.

Note: It is assumed the errors you stated in your question are standard deviations.

Comment: Yes, good point about the independence. +1. Note, that it is the errors in t and v that should be independent, not the value of t and v.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said the measurements for v and t are assumed independent.  The actual values v and t are not independent.  Thanks for the clarification, it is important.